# Question with close votes not appearing in close queue

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

There is a question for which I can see 4 close votes. I checked the Close Votes review queue, but strangely, it doesn't appear there. Why?

Some more info:

- The post is a meta post on EE.SE. There isn't much activity there, so the Close Vote queue is actually empty (at least that's how I see it).
- I did not cast a close/reopen vote myself on this question. I checked on my profile (votes>closure tab), and there is no activity shown for this question here.

The specific question is [Where is Olin Lathrop?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6954/where-is-olin-lathrop).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from the question's [timeline](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/6954/timeline); it *has* been in the Close Votes review queue, but the outcome was to [leave it open](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/146). This does not (by design) invalidate/cancel the pending close votes; the question can still be closed outside the review queue.

[image]

Since you have 10k reputation, you're able to [review reviews](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), so you could also find this review on the [review history page](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/history).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think it was working like that. And it seems strange because, although the outcome was "leave it open", it would only take one more user casting a close vote to still close it, and on the other hand, people that want to make sure it stays open can't act on it anymore.

Comment: *That styling ... lights up nicely ...*